# Problem: Can only check multiple checkbuttons together?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to generate checkbuttons for multiple items. Due to the repetition, I used a loop to initialize the widget and the default state, saving the BooleanVar() and widgets in separate lists. But by doing so, I can only check either check or uncheck all of them together.

I already tried to set different value to the BooleanVar in the list from within the loop, but to no avail.

```
ckbtnVarList = [tk.BooleanVar()]*len(ckbtnDict["Tag"])
ckbtnWdtList = [None]*len(ckbtnDict["Tag"])

for idx in range(len(ckbtnDict["Tag"])):
    ckbtnVarList[idx].set(1)
    ckbtnWdtList[idx]=ttk.Checkbutton(mainfrm, text=ckbtnDict["Text"][idx], variable=ckbtnVarList[idx]).pack()
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Comment: All the items in `ckbtnVarList` point to the same tk.BooleanVar.  The list needs to be filled in a loop or list compréhension not with the multiply operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the comments above, you need to create your list of BooleanVar's with a list comprehension or a list. The below code shows how to do this.
Since you didn't provide a complete code example, I've had to make some assumptions about your input data.

```
import tkinter as tk

ckbtnDict = {}
ckbtnDict['Tag'] = ["Tag1","Tag2","Tag3"]
ckbtnDict["Text"] = ["Txt1","Txt2","Txt3"]

mainfrm = tk.Tk()
ckbtnVarList = [tk.BooleanVar() for i in range(len(ckbtnDict["Tag"]))]
ckbtnWdtList = [None for i in range(len(ckbtnDict["Tag"]))]

for idx in range(len(ckbtnDict["Tag"])):
    ckbtnVarList[idx].set(1)
    ckbtnWdtList[idx]=tk.Checkbutton(mainfrm, text=ckbtnDict["Text"][idx], variable=ckbtnVarList[idx])
    ckbrnWdtList[idx].pack()

mainfrm.mainloop()
```

Comment: Careful `ckbtnWdtList` is a list of Nones.  As pack() returns None, it's Nones in the list not Checkbutton objects.

Comment: @TlsChris Well spotted. Edited my answer.